# Unable to call Repo.order_by properly

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to order entities from a database:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    items = Repo.all(MyModel) 
            |> Repo.preload(:model2) 
            |> Repo.preload(:model3)
            |> Repo.order_by([x], desc: x.created_at)
```

But I have an exception: `undefined function x/0`

How to fix it?

Comment: Try `|> Ecto.Query.order_by([x], desc: x.created_at)` instead.

Comment: @Dogbert `protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for [%MyModel{........}, %MyModel{........}]`

Comment: @Dogbert, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Repo.all` returns a list of structs. You can't ask the DB to order it after it was already queried. Try to build the query before you pass it to `Repo.all`. Note also that you need `Ecto.Query.order_by` and not `Repo.order_by`.

```elixir
items = 
  MyModel
  |> Ecto.Query.order_by([x], desc: x.created_at)
  |> Repo.all() 
  |> Repo.preload(:model2) 
  |> Repo.preload(:model3)
```